# How to do unit test for settimeout in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How to test a setTimeout function in react using jest/enzyme

```
setTimeout(() => {
        
}, 500);
```

I tried with this :

```
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(() => { }, 500);
```

but the test is failing with

```
Expected: [Function anonymous], 500
Received: [Function anonymous], 500
```

Can anyone please help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 500);
```

Comment: I got this : Expected: [Function mockConstructor], 500
    Received: [Function anonymous], 500

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jest.useFakeTimers()` to enable fake timers to test `setTimeout` to implement the test cases you want.

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

test('test setTimeout', () => {
  const fn = jest.fn();
  setTimeout(fn, 500);

  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(fn, 500);
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks